# Is Netty Channel.close() thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, netty

I have a Netty server, where I need to close request Channel in another thread. Is it thread safe to do this? If not, could there be some workaround to solve it? Any suggestion is appreciated!

BTW, i'm using netty-4.0.34 with NioEventLoopGroup.

AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:514

```
    @Override
    public ChannelFuture close(final ChannelPromise promise) {
    if (!validatePromise(promise, false)) {
        // cancelled
        return promise;
    }

    final AbstractChannelHandlerContext next = findContextOutbound();
    EventExecutor executor = next.executor();
    if (next.isHandlerAddedCalled() && executor.inEventLoop()) {
        next.invokeClose(promise);
    } else {
        safeExecute(executor, new OneTimeTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                next.invokeClose(promise);
            }
        }, promise, null);
    }

    return promise;
}
```

If called in another thread, the IO thread that channel has stuck to will eventually did the closure, since 'executor.inEventLoop()' will always false. Is this interpretation true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is thread safe, but you may trigger exceptions in the pipeline and on the client side if a request is in flight.

Comment: In my scenario, I started a timer thread using 'org.quartz-scheduler', and do close the Channel when time outed. Since the timer thread is not the IO thread in EventLoop, so i was wondering which thread will eventually did the closure process?

Comment: You might consider using an idle Handler to do that close.